# How to avoid redraws in flutter?

Tags: flutter

After reading a lot about providers, bloc etc. I'm not sure which of this fits the best to certain parts of my app. Let me give an example:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      periodicUpdate();
    });
  }

  void periodicUpdate() {
     setState(() {   
       isLive = event.IsHappeningNow();
     });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <
        Widget>[
      EventHeader(isLive: isLive),
      EventPhotos(photos: event.photos)
        ]);
  }
```

In this case `EventPhotos` will be redrawn every 5 seconds. But how to avoid this? I'm not sure which of the patterns is the best for this usecase. Should I use a StreamProvider for my periodic update and a Consumer inside EventHeader or should I use a ChangeNotifier for my event model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it's required to update any specific widget, not entire tree, then Consumer is the best option. Please look at below snippet where you have to add your object which you need to get notified. here in the example is CartModel, replace this with your one and try.

```
return Consumer<CartModel>(
  builder: (context, cart, child) {
    return Text("Total price: ${cart.totalPrice}");
  },
);
```